# Testing Django coupled with Celery

Tags: python, django, testing, celery

I'm having some trouble trying to figure how to test my app architecture. I've already 60% of my website complete, with full unit testing coverage (over all utility/lib functions, celery tasks as simple functions, and so on).

The problem arises when I try to test django views (plain functions) that executes celery tasks (delay method).

Example:

```
def myview(request):
  ...
  mytask.delay(myval)
  ...
```

What should be the right way to test that scenes without really generating a new task execution?

The obvious way is to set up a condition before every task delay call, executing it only if it's not in test environment, but it seems really dirty.

Any tip?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER`](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration.html#celery-always-eager) settings for test run.

It make the function to be called immediately instead of running it as a task.

---

Example django settings snippet:

```
if 'test' in sys.argv:
    CELERY_ALWAYS_EAGER = True
```